# Where can vegetarians and vegans demand changes to the legislation regarding labeling of goods?

Tags: veganism, food, labeling, shopping, legislation

One of the biggest problems I as a consumer face when shopping is that often there is **no clear labeling** of whether food classifies as being vegetarian or vegan.

While this problem is getting better gradually, I would like to know about some possibilities of speeding things up - be it by contacting organizations, government or any other way. **Are there any specialized places to deal with such queries?**

Comment: This would depend on the country, no?

Comment: Well, to a ceratin degree it surely would, but I imagine that answers to this question could be - perhaps with slight modifications - applicable for many countries. I wanted to avoid putting a specific country in the question so as to avoid 50 questions on the same topic, each with a different country.

Comment: Is "Vote with your feet and your money" the answer you didn't want anyway?

Comment: Voting with feet and money has one problem in my opinion - the ones I did not "vote" for have no idea why I did not do so. If I do not buy a vegetarian food because it does not have a vegetarian label, the company that makes that food won't know that. In the same manner, if I refuse to buy a certain product because it contains one substitutable animal ingredient, the company that is making it may not (with current spread of vegetarianism/veganism) realize they are loosing custoemrs because of this. So no, I looked for a different kind of answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that for such labels, contacting associations could be a start.

Creating a label is certainly a lot of work since you have to create all the rules that will reign over a veg*n product and make it strong and famous so that it will be a positive differentiation for goods producers and customers.

That's why think associations are the place where a veg*n label can emerge since members can participate in all the different aspect of this creation as, for example, legal and promotion.

Alternatively, an association could help you to have more influence in changing any legislation.